# android canvas calculate area colored pixels in percentage

Tags: android, canvas, percentage, pixel

I draw a canvas bitmap and trying to calculate the uncolored area in percentage.
I found some methods but they are not calculating the pixels and when I finish draw the screen and I have left a tiny uncover area, the method write that I finished.

```
 public float percentTransparent(Bitmap bm, int scale) {

    final int width = bm.getWidth();
    final int height = bm.getHeight();

    // size of sample rectangles
    final int xStep = width/scale;
    final int yStep = height/scale;

    // center of the first rectangle
    final int xInit = xStep/2;
    final int yInit = yStep/2;

    // center of the last rectangle
    final int xEnd = width - xStep/2;
    final int yEnd = height - yStep/2;

    int totalTransparent = 0;

    for(int x = xInit; x <= xEnd; x += xStep) {
        for(int y = yInit; y <= yEnd; y += yStep) {
            if (bm.getPixel(x, y) == Color.TRANSPARENT) {
                totalTransparent++;
            }
        }
    }
    return ((float)totalTransparent) / (scale * scale);

}
```

This is the method that I found.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you're doing all those pre-scaling, but conventional math you first calculate the number you need, then you scale it to the result you want. Pre-scaling can lead to errors so easily. Something like this:

```
 public float percentTransparent(Bitmap bm, float scale) {

    int width = bm.getWidth();
    int height = bm.getHeight();
    int area = width * height;
    int totalTransparent = 0;

    for(int x = 0; x <= width; x ++) {
        for(int y = 0; y <= height; y ++) {
            if (bm.getPixel(x, y) == Color.TRANSPARENT) {
                totalTransparent++;
            }
        }
    }

    // so here we know for sure that `area` is the total pixels
    // and `totalTransparent` are the total pixels not colored
    // so to calculate percentage is a simple percentage

   float percTransparent = 
        ((float)totalTransparent) / 
        ((float)area)

   // at the end you can scale your final result
  ... return something with `percTransparent` and `scale`

}
```

ps.: in case this processing is taking too long to complete (even thou it can be quite more complex to implement) using RenderScript you'll achieve processing several times faster.

Comment: Thanks but it took a lot of time

Comment: I thought it would, but that is how it works, if you want a reliable math you need to scan all the pixels and to scan all the pixels it takes time. But that's why I added the observation at the end, mentioning that with RenderScript you can make it much faster